# Object destructuring at rest example with multiple arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
onFilterChange = ({name}: {name: string}) => {
    console.log(`entered onFilterChange and name is ${name}` );
}
```

For this one argument, it compiles and runs.

However, if I was to add another argument:

```
onFilterChange = ({name}: {name: string}, {value}: {value: string}) => {
   console.log(`entered onFilterChange and name is ${name} and value is ${value}` );
        }
```

Although it does compile, at run time, there is an error:
**TypeError: _b is undefined**

The function above is invoked as following:

```
this.props.onChange({name, value});
```

So am I not seeing something obvious? A few examples on the web that I found all show just one argument -- so it works.
THanks

Comment: Shouldn't that be `({name, value}: {name: string, value: string}) => ...`? You're not passing two objects as separate positional arguments. Your current definition would expect the call `this.props.onChange({name}, {value})`.

Comment: Yep, thats the trick.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

So your signature and the way you invoke the function don't match. You need to do one of either:

```
// Keep signature and change the way you invoke:
onFilterChange = ({name}: {name: string}, {value}: {value: string})
onFilterChange({name}, {value}) <-- as separate arguments
```

Or

```
// Change signature so it takes only one argument:
onFilterChange = ({name, value}: {name: string, value: string})
onFilterChange({name, value}) <-- as single argument
```

Comment: Your second one looks most correct, and closest to the goal this guys seems to have.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the object destructuring wrongly. Because the function only has one argument, which is an object with the `name` and the `value` attribute. Therefore you have to do it like this:

```
onFilterChange = ({name, value}: {name: string, value: string }) => {
   console.log(`entered onFilterChange and name is ${name} and value is ${value}`);
}
```